# Inductive proof that sum of reciprocals of odd natural numbers diverges?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, harmonic-numbers

I am trying to prove via induction that for any natural number $N$, there exists an $n$ such that:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2i-1} > N
$$

Or

$$
1 + \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{5} + ... + \dfrac{1}{2n-1} > N
$$

I've started by attempting to use induction on $N$.  The basis step is easy.  Let $N=1$, and it is clear that $1 + \dfrac{1}{3} > N$, so $n = 2$ suffices to show the basis is true.

For the inductive step, I've started with this:

For some $k > 0$, show that

$$
1 + \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{5} + ... + \dfrac{1}{2n-1} + \dfrac{1}{2(n+1)-1} + ... + \dfrac{1}{2(n+k)-1} > N + 1 
$$

Now I've tweaked this inequality in a bunch of different ways, but I haven't been able to get closer to proving that it's true for a certain $k$.

The closest I've got is trying to show that for a given $k$,

$$
\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)-1} + ... + \dfrac{1}{2(n+k)-1} > 1
$$

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there some reason you're trying to do this specifically by induction?  Because it's quite easy to prove it diverges by comparing it to a constant multiple of the harmonic series.

Comment: Yes, I am working through "An Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning" by Iglewicz & Stoyle, and the exercises requests the use of induction to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{1}{2(n+1)-1} > \frac{1}{2(n+2)-1} > \cdots > \frac{1}{2(n+k)-1}.
$$

Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{2(n+1)-1} + \frac{1}{2(n+2)-1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2(n+k)-1}
> \frac{k}{2(n+k)-1}.
$$

The right-hand side will never be greater than $1.$ But if you can make it greater than, say, $\frac14,$ all you need to do is repeat the process four times and you will have a sum of terms that is greater than $1.$

Answer (score 1):

the first two terms are both bigger then $1/4.$   Next two terms, denominators 5,7, each reciprocal is bigger then $1/8$ sum is bigger then $1/4.$  Next denominators 9,11,13,15, each bigger than $1/16,$ sum is bigger than $1/4.$  Then denominators 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, each reciprocal bigger than $1/32,$  the sum of eight terms is bigger than $1/4.$

And so on